# Server Request Failing Because of “%0A” URL Encoding in JSON

Tags: ios, json, xcode, urlencode

I am working on an iOS chat application.

When I try to send the following text in a json request -

```
Sony%20MDR%20XB450AP%20Wired%20Headphones,%20%0AOver%20the%20Ear%20Headphone%0AWired%20Connectivity%0AOver%20the%20Head
```

The request fails. This is happening because of the "%0A" which is Carriage return character. If I remove it from the text, it works fine.

How to handle this? Please guide. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without delving deep in to your code, I would question how you are sending the request.  The text you have above is already encoded and maybe it's getting encoded a second time before transmission?

Going from iOS to server I always used plain text with normal escapes ("\n") and let the URL request encode it as needed.

Coming from the server side, I check for special characters and make sure they are properly escaped following JSON standards.